# Writing to a blob stream - how to fail and clean up?

Tags: c#, azure-storage

Using Azure storage, I'm writing to a blob using a stream. I have a method something like this:

```
    public async Task<BlobSteamContainer> GetBlobStreamAsync(string filename, string contentType = "text/csv")
    {
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{filename}--{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.csv");
        blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
        return new BlobSteamContainer(blob.Uri.ToString(), await blob.OpenWriteAsync());
    }
```

Where `BlobStreamContainer` is just a simple object so I can keep track of the filename and the stream together:

```
public class BlobSteamContainer : IDisposable
{
    public CloudBlobStream Stream { get; private set; }
    public string Filename { get; private set; }

    public BlobSteamContainer(string filename, CloudBlobStream stream)
    {
        Stream = stream;
        Filename = filename;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stream.Close();
        Stream?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And then I use it something like this:

```
using (var blobStream = await GetBlobStreamAsync(filename))
using (var outputStream = new StreamWriter(blobStream.Stream))
using (var someInputStream = ...)
{
    try
    {
        outputStream.WriteLine("write some stuff...");
        //....processing
        if (someCondition) {
            throw new MyException("can't write the file");
        }
        //....more processing
        outputStream.Flush();
    }
    catch(MyException e)
    {
        // what to do here? I want to stop writing
        // and remove any trace of the file in azure
        throw; // let the higher ups handle this
    }
}
```

Where `somecondition` is something that I know before hand (obviously there's more going on involving processing an input stream and writing out as I go). If everything is fine, then this works great. My problem is on figuring out the best way to handle the case where an exception is thrown during writing.

I tried just deleting the file in the `catch` like this:

```
 DeleteBlob(blobStream.Filename);
```

where:

```
public void DeleteBlob(string filename)
{
    var blob = container.GetBlobReference(filename);
    blob.Delete();
}
```

But the problem is that the file might not have been created yet and so this will throw a `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException` telling me the file wasn't found (and then the file will end up getting created anyway!).

So what would be the cleanest way to handle this?

Comment: What if you keep the original blob reference around and call delete on it?

Comment: @juharr - I actually ended up doing a variant on that. I had my `BlobSteamContainer` take the blob (instead of the stream) and a cancellation token source and then in the dispose I can check if the token was cancelled and delete the file _after_ everything has been closed.